# Form submit giving Undefined value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that I am generating and it has a sort button. I want to get the column the user wants to sort by but I keep getting a undefined value in sort when I try to get the value from "byColumn": 
Some help would be appreciated:

```
function createTable(data){
            var str = "<form id='tableSelect' action='javascript:void(0);'><table><thead><tr> <th>TicketNum</th><th>Recieved</th><th>SenderName</th><th>Sender Email</th><th>Subject</th><th>Tech</th><th>Status</th><th>Select</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

            for(var key in data){
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                var row = data[key];
                str += "<tr> <td>";
                str += row['TicketNum'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['Recieved'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['SenderName'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['SenderEmail'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['Subject'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['Tech'] + "</td><td>";
                str += row['Status'] + "</td><td>";
                str += "<input type='radio' name ='selectRow' value=" +row['TicketNum'] + ">" + "</td></tr>";
            }
            str += "<tr><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='TicketNum'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Recieved'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='SenderName'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='SenderEmail'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Subject'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Tech'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Status'><td> <button type ='button' value='Submit' button class=\"myButton\" onclick=\"sort();\">Sort</button> </tr>";

            str += "</tbody></table></form>";
            console.log(str);
            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = str;
        }
    function sort(){
        var table = currentTable;
        var sortby = document. getElementsByName("byColumn").value; //the error is on this line
        alert(sortby);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: If your problem is about the `NULL` values, then this is a SQL question. Might be useful if you retag the question and add the query.

Comment: I mean the null value I'm getting when I submit the form...so in the 2nd line of the sort function

Comment: Updated: use `getElementsByName("byColumn")` and loop over all to check witch checked to get value
see this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/yrub1mac/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.getElementsByName("byColumn")` to get all inputs with `name='byColumn'` not `.getElementById("byColumn")`. then loop over all radio's to get `.checked` `.value`

```js
var data = [{
'TicketNum':'TicketNum',
'Recieved':'Recieved',
'SenderName':'SenderName',
'SenderEmail':'SenderEmail',
'Subject':'Subject',
'Tech':'Tech',
'Status':'Status'
},{
'TicketNum':'TicketNum',
'Recieved':'Recieved',
'SenderName':'SenderName',
'SenderEmail':'SenderEmail',
'Subject':'Subject',
'Tech':'Tech',
'Status':'Status'
},{
'TicketNum':'TicketNum',
'Recieved':'Recieved',
'SenderName':'SenderName',
'SenderEmail':'SenderEmail',
'Subject':'Subject',
'Tech':'Tech',
'Status':'Status'
}];
createTable(data);
    function createTable(data) {
      var str = "<form id='tableSelect' action='javascript:void(0);'><table><thead><tr> <th>TicketNum</th><th>Recieved</th><th>SenderName</th><th>Sender Email</th><th>Subject</th><th>Tech</th><th>Status</th><th>Select</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    
      for (var key in data) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        var row = data[key];
        str += "<tr> <td>";
        str += row['TicketNum'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['Recieved'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['SenderName'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['SenderEmail'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['Subject'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['Tech'] + "</td><td>";
        str += row['Status'] + "</td><td>";
        str += "<input type='radio' name ='selectRow' value=" + row['TicketNum'] + ">" + "</td></tr>";
      }
      str += "<tr><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='TicketNum'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Recieved'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='SenderName'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='SenderEmail'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Subject'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Tech'><td> Sort By: <input type = 'radio' name = 'byColumn' value='Status'><td> <button type ='button' value='Submit' button class=\"myButton\" onclick=\"sort();\">Sort</button> </tr>";
    
      str += "</tbody></table></form>";
      //console.log(str);
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = str;
    }
    
    function sort() {
      //var table = currentTable;
      var col = document.getElementsByName("byColumn"); //the error is on this line
      var sortby;
      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        if (col[i].checked) {
          sortby = col[i].value;
          break;
        }
      }
      alert("sort by: "+sortby);
    
    }
```

```html
<div id='table'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **id="byColumn"** to the input named "byColumn".

The id is used by the browser, the name is used by the server.

Because you don't have an id on the tag, document.getElementById is returning null and null does not have an attribute of value.

Comment: I actually meant to be using getElementsByName("byColumn). However even with this change, I am not getting an undefined value